# How check that some specific chars not in a String

Tags: python

I'm trying to check that a symbol (e.g (`a` or `b` )) is not in a string.
I've written the bellow code, but it does not work correctly.

```
name = input("please enter name ")

while ("a" or "b" or "c" or "d") in name:
    name = input("please retry")
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'a symbol is not a string' ?

Answer (score 2):

One possible variant is using sets:

```
while {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}.intersection(name):
```

You could store this set to some variable:

```
bad_characters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}

name = input('name:')
while bad_characters.intersection(name):
    name = input('name:')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong. It has to be

```
while "a" in name or "b" in name or "c" in name or "d" in name:
```

Alternatively, you can shorten it as

```
while any(char in name for char in "abcd"):
```

Answer (score 0):

There exist more than 1 way to accomplish it, however firstly I want to explain what your code (condition) is actually doing:

```
("a" or "b" or "c" or "d") in name
```

`("a" or "b" or "c" or "d")` evaluates to `"a"` as it is first non-False (`bool("a")` produces `True`) element of alternative, so your condition is in fact equivalent to:

```
"a" in name
```

One of possible solutions is to use `re`, though this might be bit overkill there:

```
import re
name = input("please enter name ")
while re.findall(r"[abcd]",name):
    name = input("please retry")
```